# Querying custom DNS Server using boost asio resolver

Tags: c++, boost, dns, boost-asio

I would like to make a reverse DNS lookup query to some custom nameserver (by specifying ip/port) instead of the default one.

Is it possible to use boost::asio::resolver for this purpose?

I have this so far:

```
asio::ip::address_v4 ipa = asio::ip::address_v4::from_string("8.8.8.8");    
asio::ip::tcp::endpoint ep;
ep.address(ipa);

asio::io_service io_service;
asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator destination = resolver.resolve(ep);
```

Is there a way to specify dns ip/port to the resolver or to the service?

Comment: the asio ip resolver is there to resolve hostnames to ip addresses. It's pretty specialised for that purpose. When I wanted more functionality I downloaded and compiled ldns (https://nlnetlabs.nl/projects/ldns/). This is a synchronous library so you'll want to dispatch queries onto a service thread (or use an async alternative)

Comment: If you use ldns, you may also want to try my `evldns` - it's a framework for building bespoke authoritative DNS servers based on ldns and libevent.