# How to resolve DNS SRV records by boost::asio

Tags: dns, network-programming, boost-asio, asio

I know how to resolve tcp or udp DNS by boost::asio.
But how to resovle DNS SRV records?

My dns setting:

[image: dns setting]

My code:

```
        boost::asio::io_service local_io_service;
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(local_io_service);
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query local_query(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), "srv.zibuyu.me", "");
        boost::system::error_code local_error_code;
        auto result_itr = resolver.resolve(local_query, local_error_code);
        if (local_error_code != boost::system::errc::success) {
            std::cerr << "error code: " << local_error_code.message() << std::endl;
            return;
        }
```

result:

error code: Host not found (authoritative)

Comment: `SRV` records are nothing special, they are like any other types. TCP or UDP is just the transport, this is not related to the kind of records you are querying for. You should start by providing some code...

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I added more information about my question

Comment: I think you're just wrong, @PatrickMevzek. The question is not about DNS server support (sure, nothing special there). @ OP: most relevant confirmation that Asio doesn't support it directly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40979517/querying-custom-dns-server-using-boost-asio-resolver#comment69173588_40979517 - it suggests an alternative library. If @ RichardHodges suggests that, I'm pretty sure Asio is not a good fit for this type of query. Sure enough, you /can/ write your own DNS query, but it can be tricky to get the system config stuff right.

Comment: @sehe Wrong about? If you use a DNS library, querying for SRV records is like querying for any other one, there is nothing special there and this was my sole comment (besides the fact that there wasn't even code displayed at first version). Now, if boost::asio is a good DNS library or not I do not know and I did say nothing about it in either direction.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek You may be forgiven for wrongly assuming that Asio is "a DNS library".

Comment: @sehe I specifically did not assume anything in fact.